# How to Whitelist Amazon EC2 security groups on Mongolab

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mlab, aws-security-group

I am trying to Whitelist Amazon EC2 security groups (AWS only) and followed this link http://docs.mongolab.com/security/

I am getting this error "You may not define rules between a VPC group and a non-VPC group".

I searched on the internet about this and found this is an issue of EC2-Classic vs EC2-VPC. [If you created your account after 2013-12-04, it supports EC2-VPC only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html#differences-ec2-classic-vpc).

So how can I add security group of amazon here. And my security group is also in us-east-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature was only for the old "EC2 Classic" version of AWS. Now that Amazon requires everybody to use a VPC, the MongoLab security group feature doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to secure mongolab then ?

Comment: MongoLab claims that all data transfer within the same AWS region is point-to-point and cannot be sniffed. You can read more about that here: http://docs.mongolab.com/security/ I would still recommend using SSL connections if your MongoLab account supports them. You could possibly send all traffic through a NAT server in order to lock down the IP address your database accepts connections from. It's too bad the security group thing doesn't work anymore because it was the most elegant solution.